# How to access stdin and stdout in a pythonsub process when using PsExec

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess, uac, psexec

I'm running psexec in a python subprocess,

```py
import subprocess

prog = subprocess.Popen([
    'C:\\Users\\user\\tools\\PSTools\\PsExec.exe', 
    '-u', 
    'admin', 
    "-p", 
    "pass",
    "cmd.exe"], 
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
    universal_newlines=True
)
```

In doing this, psexec opens a new elevated terminal window just fine, what i'm asking is there anyway to assume control of this window with the subprocess, since it's what initially launched it? Because at the moment stdin and stdout seem to just be the subprocess that started psexec, not the terminal spawned by psexec.

Answer (score 1):

PsExec copies a file using the administrative share to the target computer then starts it as a service then that service starts the program specified. So your program has no connection.

Use COM

> Starts execution of a remote script object.
>
> object.Execute
>
> **Parameters**
>
> **object**
>
> WshRemote Object
>
> **Remarks**
>
> The Start event of the WshRemote object is fired when the script
> starts executing. Do not confuse the Execute method with the Exec
> method (of the WScript object).
>
> **Example**
>
> The following example demonstrates how the Execute method is used to
> create a WshRemote object (start an instance of a remote script).
>
> [VBScript]
>
> ```
> Dim Controller, RemoteScript
> Set Controller = WScript.CreateObject("WSHController")
> Set RemoteScript = Controller.CreateScript("remote1.js")
> RemoteScript.Execute
>
> Do While RemoteScript.Status <> 2 
>     WScript.Sleep 100
> Loop
> ```
>
> [JScript]
>
> ```
> var Controller = WScript.CreateObject("WSHController");
> var RemoteScript = Controller.CreateScript("remote1.js");
> RemoteScript.Execute();
>
> while (RemoteScript.Status != 2) {
>     WScript.Sleep(100);
> ```

From Help http://download.microsoft.com/download/winscript56/Install/5.6/W982KMeXP/EN-US/scrdoc56en.exe